# Problems getting instance of UploadedFile in Yii2

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2

I tried to upload a file to a server using `UploadedFile` class, but I can't get an Instance. In my Model:

```
public $arch;
public function rules() {
    return [[['arch'], 'file']];
}
```

Before `$model->arch = file_xxxx.jpg`

Controller:

```
$model->arch = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'arch');
```

After this `$model->arch is NULL`

View:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(
    ['id' => 'contact-form'],
    ['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]
);
print $form->field($model, 'arch')->fileInput()->label(false);
```

Comment: Explain your problem better. No result in post? errorr? what's happened

Comment: After doing this $model -> arch = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'arch'); the parameter $model -> arch I returned the file name with extention. but now $model -> arch = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'arch'); return $model -> arch = null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to get a file as follows:

```
// View
<?= $form->field($model, 'arch')->fileInput(); ?>

// Controller
$model->arch = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('arch');
```

[`getInstanceByName()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#getInstanceByName()-detail) - returns an uploaded file according to the given file input name.

Complete yii2 [Uploading Files](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html) guide.

Comment: I was having trouble too with getInstance straight from the docs. I changed to getInstanceByName and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it happened because I forgot to add

```
'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']
```

to ActiveForm options.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem and found that missing "s",

```
$names = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'filename');
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit that issue and it was my upload size in PHP ini file. It was 2MB and file was 2MB. I extended it to 200MB and all worked!

Answer (score 0):

Check the upload error code. If the code number is 6, it is UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR meaning "Missing a temporary folder". Solution maybe ..:

1. modify write access of temporary folder stated in upload_tmp_dir value of php.ini
2. increase post_max_size in php.ini from 8M to a higher value
3. increase upload_max_filesize in php.ini to a higher value